# No matter what I do Chrome inspector won't recognise my sass source map

Tags: compass-sass, fanstatic

I have tried Inline, file, absolute and relative paths and Chrome is ignoring my source map. I am however using Fanstatic caching but I thought this wouldn't make any difference if I am using an inline source map with absolute paths. I have removed the paths below for privacy's sake.

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = ""
sass_dir = ""
images_dir = ""
javascripts_dir = ""
environment = :development

add_import_path ""

relative_assets = false
sass_options = {:sourcemap => :inline}
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/
This one could be useful.

Comment: Been there, done that - unfortunately